# Are url parameter names case sensitive in php If not, can they easily be normalized (and made lowercase, etc.)?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm writing a spec for part of our webapp. I don't use PHP much.

I'd like to use camelcase for the parameter names to make them easier to read (SubTitle, etc.)  but wanted to make sure that would not be a problem.

Comment: Query string and element parameter names are predominantly in lower-case (imo) but there's no barrier to using other forms. I get the impression Microsoft/.net developers prefer camel case. I'd not bother with converting though - if you prefer camel case, use it throughout.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are case-sensitive. If you want to normalize them anyway you can use: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php